# C# Xamarin - Popover segue causes anonymous build error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, segue, viewcontroller

Firstly, it may be helpful for you to have the relevant environment details to rule out environmental factors:

```
Dev PC Environment 
_______________________
Windows 10 Enterprise 64 Bit
Intel Core i7 3.40GHz 16GB RAM 
Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Xamarin 4.0.3.214 (0dd817c)
Xamarin.iOS 9.6.1.8 (3a25bf1)


Macbook (Agent) Environment - used to build and simulate
______________________
OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4
Simulator Version 9.3
Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)
```

Looking through SO I can't resolve the issue via the following questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674862/present-as-popover-segues-and-view-size),  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303464/how-can-i-segue-between-two-xib-files-in-xamarin) and generally within the Xamarin documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/).

I have experienced this error in Xamarin.iOS when building:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App5.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
1>  Generated session id: 22824a3fd65b76ad8c03fd7694e35be1
1>  Generated build app name: App5iOS
1>  Connecting to Mac server 192.168.1.197...
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(997,3): error : 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have a ViewController named MainViewController which is blank, save for a UIButton named `MenuButton` which my MainViewController.designer.cs says is correctly attributed as an `[Outlet]`.

I `CTRL + LEFT CLICKED` from `MenuButton` in `Main.storyboard` and correctly dragged to the `NavigationDropdownViewController` which created the Segue. I named this segue `NavigationMenuSegue`.

[image: Image shoing segue from MainViewController to NavigationBarDropdownViewController]

Within the `Widget` tab I set the following:

[image: Segue properties]

If I choose either "Present As Popover" from the "Adaptive Segue" tree or the "Popover" from the "Deprecated Segues" tree, the build action encounters the error above.

Oddly, if I choose the "Present Modally" or "Push" options the drop down appears on clicking the `MenuButton` - albeit in the wrong position! Essentially I want it to toggle as a popover with a caret pointing towards the menu button (this is what was asked of me!)

All I want is the drop down menu to appear below the `MenuButton` much in the same style as a hamburger web based menu does... I am concerned that this is not an isolated issue according to Xamarin's Bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37780)

In Xcode I could simply drop Views and work with .xibs to easily segue - I just don't seem to be understanding Xamarin's designer perhaps.

Here is my MainViewController.cs

```
partial class MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    public MainViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
}

[Register ("MainViewController")]
partial class MainViewController
{
    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UIButton MenuButton { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UIView MainView { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (MenuButton != null) {
            MenuButton.Dispose ();
            MenuButton = null;
        }
        if (MainView != null) {
            MainView.Dispose ();
            MainView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The NaviagationBarDropdownViewController.cs

```
   [Register ("NavigationBarDropdownViewController")]
    partial class NavigationBarDropdownViewController
    {
        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIButton LogoutButton { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIImageView LogoutIcon { get; set; }

        // omitted the other [Outlet]s for the five other buttons in the view for brevity   

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIView NavigationBarDropdownView { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            // omitted for brevity
        }
    }
```

Is the Popover Segue build error a bug in the framework or am I going down the wrong path entirely in creating what is a very simple Menu -> Dropdown UI pattern!

Thanks for taking the time to read this and contributing towards a solution - cause I can't afford to lose any more hair over this!

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

I'm hoping this helps anyone else experiencing this issue using the Xamarin.IOS designer.

I understand from speaking with a Xamarin developer that the issue has now been resolved in the latest 4.1.x build (which is currently in their Beta channel). However, those who would rather use a stable build (i.e. 4.0.x) then follow these steps to resolve the anonymous build error:

Firstly, select the UI element you wish to trigger the Popover, in my case it was the `MenuButton`. Note the `LocalizationID`, you can find this by clicking the element within the designer and viewing the "Properties" window. In my case the `MenUButton`'s LocalizationID was `204`:

[image]

Now click on the Segue and again navigate to the `"Properties"` window. Select `"Present As Popover"` from the `"Segue"` drop down.

Next, insert the `LocalizationID` for the tigger (in my case `MenuButton`'s ID). Note that the ID must be enclosed within `["INSERT_YOUR_LOCALIZATION_ID_HERE"]` so in my example I entered `["204"]`:

[image]

After following these steps the project will build and the Popover will function correctly.

Happy days.